# Is it possible to get the Tux logo on the text-based boot?

Tags: boot, 11.10, text-mode, framebuffer

On Knoppix-based distros, you get a nice Tux logo on the left of the screen during text boot. Is this possible to get on Ubuntu?

[image: Welcome to the KNOPPIX live Linux-on-CD!]

Comment: @UriHerrera You didn't understand it correctly. I dont want a themed boot menu

Comment: You want a Picture on a text boot menu, that sounds like theming to me, anyways if you didn't mean Grub, the next thing that loads right after it is plymouth and ply mouth has a text boot too.. so a theme for plymouth it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This logo is a [kernel compile option](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/LOGO.html) called "CONFIG_LOGO" - it is a boolean value - when it is set to true it displays the Logo on boot.

This logo appears through a framebuffer - that is how you get the graphical logo.

The Ubuntu kernels don't appear to use this compile option and hence it defaults to "false" which disables the logo.  The probable reason for this is that it would interfere with Plymouth - you'll need to compile your own kernel to do this...

You'll need to install a framebuffer package such as `v86d` and configure it correctly with your monitor resolution as per this [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Framebuffer#Framebuffer_Resolution).

You'll also need to ensure when booting you do not use KMS - i.e. `nomodeset` or `i915.modeset=0` type parameters.