# How to I will add jpg or gif or png (logo or emblem) in Terminal

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to get the tux logo on the text based boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80938/is-it-possible-to-get-the-tux-logo-on-the-text-based-boot)

I want to add jpg logo  in Terminal..but not ascii format

Comment: As a background image ? Like this ? http://bodhizazen.net/img/Terminal2.png

Comment: yes thank you but ubuntu 10.04 ..as shell script code  I want to  add..or Terminal starting as ascii code !!

Comment: Glad you like the web pages / blog. Not sure what you want for your terminal.

Comment: Thank you..I want to add Terminal when Starting....small logo..not background

Comment: Please clearly clarify what you want to achieve! Logo = picture = background -> that's our vision.

Comment: thank you very much...examle : penguin logo ...http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gg285ZHSJ-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click -> Profile -> Profile Preferences -> Background:

[image]

UPDATE:

Apparently the question is about how to add a greeting message to the Terminal:

Usually this is done by adding a message to `/etc/issue`, `/etc/banner` or `/etc/motd`, depending on what conditions you want the message to be displayed.
`/etc/bash.bashrc` might work as well:

```
echo "  I'M THE GREAT CORNHOLIO!!!  "
echo "       ________________       "
echo "      /                \      "
echo "     / /          \ \   \     "
echo "     |                  |     "
echo "    /                  /      "
echo "   |      ___\ \| | / /       "
echo "   |      /           |       "
echo "   |      |     __    |       "
echo "  /       |       \   |       "
echo "  |       |        \  |       "
echo "  |       |       __  |       "
echo "  |      __\     (_o) |       "
echo "  |     |             |       "
echo "   \    ||             \      "
echo "    |   |__             \     "
echo "    |   |           (*___\    "
echo "    |   |       _     |       "
echo "    |   |    //_______|       "
echo "    |  /       |_|_|_|___/\   "
echo "     \|       \ -         |   "
echo "      |       _----_______/   "
echo "      |      /                "
echo "      |_____/                 "
```

Comment: ok..thank you but ubuntu 10.04 ...

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 is the same.

Comment: Thank you..I want to add Terminal when Starting....small logo..not background

Comment: I've updated my answer with ASCII logo - probably that's what you want.

Comment: than you very much..