# Add Tux logo during boot with kernel recompiling

Tags: boot, kernel

I would like to add Tux boot logo during text-based boot (just like the old times). I already tried to set logo in Device Drivers--->Graphic Support--->Bootup Logo.
I also tried to edit grub configurations and install v86d, but this doesn't give me anything (solution provided by [Is it possible to get the Tux logo on the text-based boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80938/is-it-possible-to-get-the-tux-logo-on-the-text-based-boot)).
Framebuffering is enabled everywhere.
Every help will be appreciated!

Comment: do you want the logo in grub?  or the boot splash?

Comment: @ravery bootsplash

Comment: plymouth is installed? plymouth themes are stored at `usr/share/plymouth/themes`. you could modify one of the existing themes.  or download a theme to modify and add to this directory. At, `usr/share/plymoouth` there is a logo.... that may do it also

Comment: @ravery I need to do this with kernel recompiling :(

Comment: ahhh, opps I didn't see that. I don't know where to find it there sorry